# создание адаптивного блока

Tags: html, css, responsive

У меня есть блок родительский. Когда я внутреннему блоку даю ширину больше, чем было, то в мобильной версии он съезжает вправо. Как вернуть его на место в мобильной версии?

```css
.content-section .content {
  max-width: 940px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px;
  margin: 0 15px 40px 0;
}

.content-section .content .lesson-item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 170px;
  max-width: 430px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="content-section">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="lesson-item">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Например в CSS я дал не `430px` а `450px` и блок съехал вправо в мобильной версии, а вернуть на место не получается, но использовать `450px` я должен. Как быть? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: box-sizng:border-box

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский в `content-section`?

Comment: *{box-sizing:border-box} это запишите в самый верх css файла

Comment: и да правый и левый наружный отступ обнулите ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский тоже в `*{box-sizing:border-box}` прописать `margin:0 padding:0`?

Comment: ну вот смотрите у вас написано так : margin: 0 15px 40px 0;  т.е это говорит о том что у вас наружные оступы сверху 0, право 15, низ 40 лево 0 и как раз эти 15 пикселов мешают ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский убрал, но не помогло(

Comment: как не помогло ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YgpqbX